# Why does my function on the server return true but returns false on the client side in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I have `hasCompleted` function that returns `true` or `false` which is in the server file file:

```
Smaples.helpers({
 hasCompleted(userId) {
    // …
    switch (this.frequency) {
      case Frequency.ONE_TIME:{
        return measures.fetch().every(measure => {

          console.log(
            'measure.hasCompleted(userId)', //  true
            measure.hasCompleted(userId),
          );

          measure.hasCompleted(userId);
        });
      }
    }
   // …
  },
})
```

But when it comes to the client side the above function returns `false`.

On the client side using `useTracker`:

```
  const hasCompleted = useTracker(
    () => sample.hasCompleted(Meteor.myFunctions.getCurrentUserId()),
  );
  console.log(
    'survey.hasCompleted(Meteor.myFunctions.getCurrentUserId())', // false
    survey.hasCompleted(Meteor.myFunctions.getCurrentUserId()),
  );
  console.log('hasCompleted', hasCompleted); // false
```

The way I access helpers from the client side, is this wrong?

### Attempts

inside `hasCompleted` I manually return `true` and the console shows `true`:

```
Smaples.helpers({
 hasCompleted(userId) {
    // …
    switch (this.frequency) {
      case Frequency.ONE_TIME:{
        return true; // changed
    }
   // …
  },
})
```

Also, I thought if

```
console.log(measure.hasCompleted(userId))
```

after returning it could be changed, but

```
console.log(measure.hasCompleted(userId))
```

still returns `true`:

```
Smaples.helpers({
 hasCompleted(userId) {
    // …
    switch (this.frequency) {
      case Frequency.ONE_TIME:{
        return measures.fetch().every(measure => {
          measure.hasCompleted(userId);
          console.log(
            'measure.hasCompleted(userId)', //  true
            measure.hasCompleted(userId),
          );
        });
      }
    }
   // …
  },
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very probably just miss a `return` in the callback of your `measures.every()` call:

[Array.prototype.every doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#return_value):

> `true` if the `callbackFn` function returns a truthy value for every array element. Otherwise, `false`.

```js
Smaples.helpers({
 hasCompleted(userId) {
    // …
    switch (this.frequency) {
      case Frequency.ONE_TIME:{
        return measures.fetch().every(measure => {

          console.log(
            'measure.hasCompleted(userId)', //  true
            measure.hasCompleted(userId),
          );

          // Make sure to return a truthy value if the item passes your condition
          return measure.hasCompleted(userId);
        });
      }
    }
   // …
  },
})
```

Note: in case your array is empty (no documents), `every` always returns `true`; be careful if this is not what you want.

Not sure about your Server part since there is no information about it.